# Send email flask google app engine - Invalid sender format

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to make a simple flask contact form on google app engine. I'm new to both.

There are two links which I have used to help me:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail
http://www.boxcontrol.net/adding-contact-form-to-your-site-using-flask-and-python3.html#.VWnRUlzBzGc

This is my code:

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from google.appengine.api import mail
from forms import ContactForm


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'YourSuperSecreteKey'


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    return 'Hello World!'


@app.route('/contact', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            return 'Please fill in all fields <p><a href="/contact">Try Again!!!</a></p>'
        else:
            message = mail.EmailMessage(sender=form.name.data,
                            subject="Contact")
            message.to = form.email.data
            message.body = form.message.data
            message.send()
            return "Successfully  sent message!"
        elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**form.py**

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, validators

def CheckNameLength(form, field):
  if len(field.data) < 4:
    raise ValidationError('Name must have more then 3 characters')

class ContactForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Your Name:', [validators.DataRequired(), CheckNameLength])
    email = StringField('Your e-mail address:', [validators.DataRequired(), validators.Email('your@email.com')])
    message = TextAreaField('Your message:', [validators.DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Send Message')
```

The error I get is: **Sorry, unexpected error: Invalid sender format**

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

---

```
Exception on /contact [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384668257912944999/lib/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384668257912944999/lib/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384668257912944999/lib/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384668257912944999/lib/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384668257912944999/lib/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384668257912944999/main.py", line 40, in contact
    message.send()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 1115, in send
    raise ERROR_MAP[e.application_error](e.error_detail)
BadRequestError: Invalid sender format
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you following the rules they have for who is allowed to be in the from field of the emails?

> The email address of the sender, the From address. The sender address must be one of the following types:
>
> - The address of a registered administrator for the application. You can add administrators to an application using the Administration Console.
> - The address of the user for the current request signed in with a Google Account. You can determine the current user's email address with the Users API. The user's account must be a Gmail account, or be on a domain managed by Google Apps.
> - Any valid email receiving address for the app (such as xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com).
> - Any valid email receiving address of a domain account, such as support@example.com. Domain accounts are accounts outside of the Google domain with email addresses that do not end in @gmail.com or @APP-ID.appspotmail.com.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail