# google.appengine.runtime.apiproxy_errors.ApplicationError: ApplicationError: 2 Invalid sender format

Tags: email, flask, google-cloud-platform

I try to send an email from python Flask server on GCP.

I use this format, which should comply (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30548228/5414407))

```
My_Project___{task_name}@{self.project_id}.appspotmail.com
```

Any idea what's not following the needed format?

Comment: Please check [mail APi for Python 3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/mail) as there are some subtle differences from Python 2. The reference that you provided is using Python 2 and there are some updates specially made for Python 3. Please check [code sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/main/appengine/standard_python3/bundled-services) for additional guide.

Comment: Did my previous comment work?